# Pandas: Compute median of data per hour, group by date

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset containing data from taxi rides in the city of Chicago. The data contains information such as Taxi ID, Timestamp, Fare etc. among others. A sample of the data is shown below with the timestamps in pandas datetime:

[image]

For a given timeframe, which can be an hour/day/week, I want to compute the median amount: how much a typical taxi makes and analyze its profile throughout the dataset's timeframe. For example, if I want to consider the data hourly, I am visualizing how the median revenue of a taxi changes by hour by creating a pivot table between Taxi ID and the Hour, and then taking the median of the total amount made.

```
taxiByHour = taxiData.pivot_table(index='Taxi ID',columns='Hour',aggfunc=sum)
taxiByHour.fillna(0,inplace=True)
taxiByHour['Trip Total'].median().plot(kind='bar', x='hour', rot = 0, color = 'green')
```

This is obviously computing the median for all rides that have taken place in the data during that hour. How can I extend this such that, I can display this median value by hour continuously by date for all the timespan in the data? So if I am considering data for a week, I want to display the profile of the median revenue of each hour for 24*7 = 168 hours.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your underlying data?

Comment: Added a picture with some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the data in rows with `columns=["Taxi ID", "Timestamp", "Fare"]` then convert the timestamp to `datetime.datetime` format (if it isn't already) and make it the index, i.e. `df.index=df["Timestamp"]`. Then you can use `pd.DataFrame.resample` with a rule (in your case `'H'`) and a built in method (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#resampling) or `.apply` your own. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1],[2]],index=[datetime(2017,1,1,1),datetime(2017,1,1,2)])
resampled = df.resample('H').median()
```